# Get a auth user by its uid in Firestore cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have cloud function triggered when a new object is added to a collection. It looks like this:

```
exports.emailAdmin = functions.firestore
  .document('user-books/{userId}/books/{ASIN}')
  .onWrite(event => {
```

That `event.data.data()` is an object added to the sub-collection ("books"). The `userId` comes from the Firebase authentication system. I.e. a user signed in, and added an object to the collection "user-books" with his/her "uid".

I tried:

```
firestore
    .collection('users')
    .doc(uid)
    .get()
```

But that, "of course", fails because *I* don't have a collection called "users". How do I get to the "authentication database"?

The purpose is to convert the "uid" to that person's "email".

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Import firebase-admin:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

Then fetch the auth user:

```
const uid = ...;
const authUser = await admin.auth().getUser(uid); // this returns a promise, so use await or .then()

console.log(authUser.email);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no access to the user collection from firebase. What I did was creating a separate User's Table where I store all the users Data. I add the new user to my collection on the onCreate Hook like this:

```
exports.addNewUserToUserTable = functions.auth.user()
.onCreate(event => {
    let user = event.data;
    let database = admin.firestore();

    return database.collection('user').doc(user.uid).set({
        email: user.email
    });
```

Another problem is, that at the moment it is not possible to get the logged in user's ID on Firestore Database Triggers (It works for the real time db). I'm still waiting for this feature to be released...

Comment: Is it safe to do that? I want to make UID accessible from Firestore and that isn't safe, is it?

Comment: I don't see any security issues here. My users collection is protected by a firestore security rule and I'm not storing any passwords in there. I hope this helps.

Comment: I would need users to access UIDs to see which blog posts they created(profiles) so I guess I can't just make a rule unless I access it only from cloud functions.

Comment: If this code doesn't work for anyone here is workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44125209/7387243

Comment: @Telion - As far as I understand you wan't to give access for  each user to only access it's own document in the created User collection. You could achieve that by creating a cloud function on a firestore hock, where you simply check if the user is accessing it's own ID. The only negative point is, that you can not get the users UID in a Firestore Database Trigger yet. :(  I hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm struggling with the same problem and am not getting very far with attempts to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question might be incomplete- you reference an event.data.data() line that didn't appear in your code snippet. Could you review it and add it if it's missing?

Also, just to clarify your purpose- you want to be able to access the email address of a user who has been authenticated, and tag it to the book that has been added by that user?

Thanks.

Comment: the `event` is the first and only argument mentioned in the last line of the first code snippet.

Comment: No, the idea is to retroactively fetch the user object from the uid in cloud function. There is no brower or logged in session in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Since `context.auth.uid` is not available for firestore. You can assign userId to document and read it in the rules.

```
match /collectionA/{docId} {
  allow update: if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
}

exports.createProfile = functions.firestore
.document('collectionA/{docId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => { // or onUpdate
  const newValue = snap.data();
  const {userId} = newValue;
});
```